# How to sort Magento product list by product rate?

Tags: sorting, magento

I would like to sort product list by product rate. Is it possible?

I googled about it, but I only found how to sort by newest, name, category.

Comment: @Joseph Mastey // always thank you for your editing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below path in Magento Admin panel

**Dashboard --> System --> Configuration -->Catalog--> Frondend -->**

You can see the `Product Listing Sort by` with `drop-down` options

Select the **Price** in Product Listing Sort by **drop-down**.

Once you choosed the Price in drop-down All the products will sort with price range.

Comment: Question is how to sort product by Rate not Price.

Comment: What is the difference between product price / rate ? @JaydipKanasagra

Comment: Price is product price and Rate is product Review and Rating so many difference between them.

Comment: "Rate" is not in any way related to "Rating"! Just in case you have doubt, check Google's definition for rate here - https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20rate

Hence, my solution answers whatever the user has asked in the question. Read the question properly, check if the given answer answers the question and then upvote/downvote.

Comment: Rate and Price also are different.

Comment: In the given question’s perspective or even Magento’s perspective, could you explain what is the difference between price and rate for a product? @JaydipKanasagra

Comment: Please refer the right answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618349/how-to-add-rating-to-sort-list-in-magento-1-7

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51710/how-can-i-add-a-sort-by-rating

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116199/how-can-we-fetch-top-rated-products-as-collections-in-magento

Comment: @JaydipKanasagra Are you even understanding or reading the question asked and what I am saying? This question asks for RATE, not RATING. I don't know how else to explain you!